# Enabled https with certbot steps, now site won't load

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, https, ubuntu-18.04, certbot

This is my first project I've deployed and I followed the steps to enable https here: https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-nginx.html

Eventually my site errors: took too long to respond.

Ideally, I'd like to resolve this, but I am not sure how to debug. In the meantime, I'd like to disable https so my site will load.

Any guidance would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I added https to the Firewall section on my Lightsail instance and it resolved the issue.